# Is there a way to prevent a word with a hyphen from being split when wrapped?

Tags: support, markdown

If I write a word that itself contains a hyphen, and it happens to be near the end of a line, then it will get split at the hyphen during word wrapping.

But sometimes this has undesirable (to me, anyways) results. For example, in a recent post I made, I typed this:

```
- The active chemical in most consumer-grade CA glues† is ethyl 2-cyanoacrylate (CAS [7085-85-0][cas]).
```

And it ended up rendered like this:

[image]

If "7085-85-0" was actually a *word*, it'd probably make sense, but it's a numeric identifier whose format contains hyphens, so it's a little awkward to split it. Plus, only one character ended up on the next line.

Is there some way (or hack) to prevent certain words from being split, when that word contains a hyphen? I.e. to have it be treated like a non-hyphenated word?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replacing the - with a non-breaking Hyphen works as well: `&#8209;`

Giving: `CAS [7085&#8209;85&#8209;0][cas]` in your makrdown.

Or copy it as char:

> ‑

giving

`CAS [7085‑85‑0][cas]`

Result:

- The active chemical test to  in most consumer-grade CA glues† is ethyl 2-cyanoacrylate (CAS [7085‑85‑0](https://example.com/test)).

Without non-breaking hyphen:

- The active chemical test to  in most consumer-grade CA glues† is ethyl 2-cyanoacrylate (CAS [7085-85-0](https://example.com/test)).

Here is the Windows Character map tool to find and select that character:

[image: charactermap tool]

Find it on Windows 10 via the Search: "Character" should do the trick

Comment: even better than mine with half the entities

Comment: You don't even need to use the entities with this version, as you aren't inserting an invisible character. You can just copy-paste an actual non-breaking hyphen and it will still be readable in the editor as well.

Comment: @animuson fair point

Comment: It's also semantically concise and accurate, which gives me the warm fuzzies because I'm a huge nerd.

Comment: @JasonC your nerdness is served ...

Answer (score 4):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60697458/2518200) answer, looks like you can use a *word joiner* character  immediately before and after the dash. So in markdown it would look like this:

```
7085&#8288;-&#8288;85&#8288;-&#8288;0
```

The above text is 7085-85-0 with `&#8288;` before and after the dashes.

Live test:

- The active chemical in most consumer-grade CA glues† is ethyl 2-cyanoacrylate (CAS [7085⁠-⁠85⁠-⁠0][cas]).

Comment: Trying it now and... beautiful. Nailed it.

Comment: @JasonC I think rene's solution is even better, feel free to accept theirs.

Comment: Ah, I agree, actually. The non-breaking hyphen is more semantically appropriate. But I learned something from this, too. Sorry for the emotional checkbox roller coaster, haha. Thank you!!

Comment: This is actually super useful in cases where the character isn't a hyphen but you want to accomplish the same thing (and there's no non-breaking version of the character). Filed away for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

Try homoglyphs:

test˗test..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
test۔test..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
test‑test..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
test‑test..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
test‒test..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
test⁃test..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
test−test..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
test⁃test..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
test−test..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
testⲺtest..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
test﹘test..........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Hm, that renders [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az8Aw.png) for me (Chrome, Windows). Was that the intent?

Comment: @JasonC Yes, isn't that the expected result?

Comment: I don't know, lol. Let me try replacing my hyphens with full-width ones.

Comment: @JasonC My mistake, it isn't working on Chrome.  It renders fine on Firefox...

Comment: Unfortunately, it [still splits it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onWnf.png). Also confirmed it splits *after* the hyphen by [removing a few letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frRwa.png).

Comment: @JasonC I'll try some of the other homoglyphs: ˗۔‐‑‒–⁃−Ⲻ﹘.  Maybe one of those will render on Chrome.

Comment: @JasonC Try this: `‑`.

Comment: Which one is that? It actually got posted as a vanilla U+002D hyphen in your comment. Rene's answer, though, identified a working character [U+2011](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2011) (non-breaking hyphen). Oh I see your edit. Interesting. FYI, on Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqaxn.png

Comment: @JasonC It's the MODIFIER LETTER MINUS SIGN (`U+02D7`).  I chose it because it looks close to a regular hyphen on all browsers.

Comment: Huh, I wonder why it got transformed. Anyways, +1 for your persistence here, haha. Thank you, it's very much appreciated. :)